# Einstein field equation,pde and differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

I'm a math undergraduate student with some interest in mathematical physics with basic knowledge of partial differential equation.

When I was reading a wikipedia article about einstein field equation,it said

> when fully written out, the EFE are a system of ten coupled, nonlinear, hyperbolic-elliptic partial differential equations.

my question is if einstein equation is a partial differential equation, why can't you solve it normally,why do you need tensor analysis/riemannian geometry for, and can any partial differential equation be written using the languange of tensor, differential geometry,etc?

I apologize for my minimal understanding of this subject, but I haven't learn any tensor calculus yet

Comment: You can. But if you solve it, you only get a local solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ten is simply the number of distinct components of a second order symmetric tensor in a space of dimension four. Writing these equations in tensor form enables us to write EFE as a single equation instead of ten, just as $\vec F=m\ddot{\vec x}$ is a single vector equation written in place of three scalar equations.

Comment: This does not explain why it is formulated in curved space.

Comment: I still don't understand any tensor calculus, but can you treat einstein field equation like the usual pde, and can any pde be written and solved in tensor form, if so what is the difference if you use usual method to solve pde? thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want to know: where did you read of a tensor method to SOLVE pde's? Writing a system of pde's in more compact form can help to find some shortcuts or to give ideas about the solutions, but if you are to solve them (numerically, for instance), then the methods are the usual ones.

Comment: Instead, tensor analysis is crucial to understand how EFE were derived (i.e. to understand the physics behind those equations), but has little to do with solving them.

Comment: okay, thanks,but why is riemannian geometry needed?, is it pde on a riemann manifold or something?

Comment: That's because, in Einstein's view, a free-falling body (e.g. a planet) moves along a geodesic line in space-time. But a space-time with geodesic which are not straight must be curved: Einstein related this curvature to the density of energy-momentum and to do that all the machinery of curved manifolds is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know Einstein field equations, then you must have heard of metric tensor and curvature tensor and their relationship to the field equations.

In local coordinates (normal coordinates) we can make the first derivative of the metric tensor to vanish at a given point but not the second derivative simultaneously. But curvature tensor is a function of both first and second derivatives of the metric tensor, so local coordinates doesnt always help in finding global solutions.